# Extracting the information of angle and axis

Tags: c++, opencv

Here I got the code of extracting the orientation of the object in the image. I am new to OpenCV and C++. But I need to get this work done.
My question is, how to extract, write out the information of the angle and axis in this code?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
// Function declarations
void drawAxis(Mat&, Point, Point, Scalar, const float);
double getOrientation(const vector<Point> &, Mat&);
void drawAxis(Mat& img, Point p, Point q, Scalar colour, const float scale = 0.2)
{
    double angle = atan2((double)p.y - q.y, (double)p.x - q.x); // angle in radians
    double hypotenuse = sqrt((double)(p.y - q.y) * (p.y - q.y) + (p.x - q.x) * (p.x - q.x));
    // Here we lengthen the arrow by a factor of scale
    q.x = (int)(p.x - scale * hypotenuse * cos(angle));
    q.y = (int)(p.y - scale * hypotenuse * sin(angle));
    line(img, p, q, colour, 1, LINE_AA);
    // create the arrow hooks
    p.x = (int)(q.x + 9 * cos(angle + CV_PI / 4));
    p.y = (int)(q.y + 9 * sin(angle + CV_PI / 4));
    line(img, p, q, colour, 1, LINE_AA);
    p.x = (int)(q.x + 9 * cos(angle - CV_PI / 4));
    p.y = (int)(q.y + 9 * sin(angle - CV_PI / 4));
    line(img, p, q, colour, 1, LINE_AA);
}
double getOrientation(const vector<Point> &pts, Mat &img)
{
    //Construct a buffer used by the pca analysis
    int sz = static_cast<int>(pts.size());
    Mat data_pts = Mat(sz, 2, CV_64F);
    for (int i = 0; i < data_pts.rows; i++)
    {
        data_pts.at<double>(i, 0) = pts[i].x;
        data_pts.at<double>(i, 1) = pts[i].y;
    }
    //Perform PCA analysis
    PCA pca_analysis(data_pts, Mat(), PCA::DATA_AS_ROW);
    //Store the center of the object
    Point cntr = Point(static_cast<int>(pca_analysis.mean.at<double>(0, 0)),
        static_cast<int>(pca_analysis.mean.at<double>(0, 1)));
    //Store the eigenvalues and eigenvectors
    vector<Point2d> eigen_vecs(2);
    vector<double> eigen_val(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        eigen_vecs[i] = Point2d(pca_analysis.eigenvectors.at<double>(i, 0),
            pca_analysis.eigenvectors.at<double>(i, 1));
        eigen_val[i] = pca_analysis.eigenvalues.at<double>(i);
    }
    // Draw the principal components
    circle(img, cntr, 3, Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2);
    Point p1 = cntr + 0.02 * Point(static_cast<int>(eigen_vecs[0].x * eigen_val[0]), static_cast<int>(eigen_vecs[0].y * eigen_val[0]));
    Point p2 = cntr - 0.02 * Point(static_cast<int>(eigen_vecs[1].x * eigen_val[1]), static_cast<int>(eigen_vecs[1].y * eigen_val[1]));
    drawAxis(img, cntr, p1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
    drawAxis(img, cntr, p2, Scalar(255, 255, 0), 5);
    double angle = atan2(eigen_vecs[0].y, eigen_vecs[0].x); // orientation in radians
    return angle;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Load image
    CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, "{@input | joint2.bmp | input image}");
    parser.about("This program demonstrates how to use OpenCV PCA to extract the orientation of an object.\n");
    parser.printMessage();
    Mat src = imread(parser.get<String>("@input"));
    // Check if image is loaded successfully
    if (src.empty())
    {
        cout << "Problem loading image!!!" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    imshow("src", src);
    // Convert image to grayscale
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(src, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    // Convert image to binary
    Mat bw;
    threshold(gray, bw, 200, 255, THRESH_BINARY | THRESH_OTSU);
    // Find all the contours in the thresholded image
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    findContours(bw, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        // Calculate the area of each contour
        double area = contourArea(contours[i]);
        // Ignore contours that are too small or too large
        if (area < 1e2 || 1e5 < area) continue;
        // Draw each contour only for visualisation purposes
        drawContours(src, contours, static_cast<int>(i), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
        // Find the orientation of each shape
        getOrientation(contours[i], src);
    }

    imshow("output", src);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the image of the object: 
[image: Section of white corner pipe]

And here is the result:

[image: Section of white corner pipe with edges outlined by algorithm]

As you see, it finds orientation correctly, but I need the information about the angle and which is which axis to be written. 
Will be very grateful if someone knows how to do it!

EDIT: I have figured out how to find the information about the center, area, and the angle.

```
    /// Get the moments
    vector<Moments> mu(contours.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        mu[i] = moments(contours[i]);
    }
    ///  Get the mass centers
    vector<Point2f> mc(contours.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        //add 1e-5 to avoid division by zero
        mc[i] = Point2f(static_cast<float>(mu[i].m10 / (mu[i].m00 + 1e-5)),
            static_cast<float>(mu[i].m01 / (mu[i].m00 + 1e-5)));
    }


    imshow("output", src);

    cout << "\t Info: Area and angle \n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << " * Contour[" << i << "]  - Center: "<< mc[i] 
            << " - Area: " << contourArea(contours[i]) << " - Angle: " << getOrientation(contours[i],src)*180/CV_PI << endl;
    }
```

But still don't know how to denote which arrow is which axis in the image.

Comment: what is the return value of getOrientation ?

Comment: @nayab umm, radians? 
`double angle = atan2(eigen_vecs[0].y, eigen_vecs[0].x); // orientation in radians`
I mean it is in `double`

Comment: I mean what orientation does it represent?  what are the axes for your object and what world axes with respect to which you want to find the orientation?

Comment: @nayab Oh, I want to find the inclination of x axis of the object from the horizontal in the image and write it out. i guess, the blue line represents x-axis, green is y.

Comment: The interpretation of the local coordinate system is entirely up to you. PCA gives you the axes of largest variance in descending order. You decide what you do with it. It is all there in `getOrientation()`. You just need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured out everything I need (almost).
Here is the final code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
// Function declarations
void drawAxis(Mat&, Point, Point, Scalar, const float);
double getOrientation(const vector<Point> &, Mat&);
string s = "";
void drawAxis(Mat& img, Point p, Point q, Scalar colour, const float scale = 0.2)
{
    double angle = atan2((double)p.y - q.y, (double)p.x - q.x); // angle in radians
    double hypotenuse = sqrt((double)(p.y - q.y) * (p.y - q.y) + (p.x - q.x) * (p.x - q.x));
    // Here we lengthen the arrow by a factor of scale
    q.x = (int)(p.x - scale * hypotenuse * cos(angle));
    q.y = (int)(p.y - scale * hypotenuse * sin(angle));
    line(img, p, q, colour, 1, LINE_AA);

    // create the arrow hooks
    p.x = (int)(q.x + 9 * cos(angle + CV_PI / 4));
    p.y = (int)(q.y + 9 * sin(angle + CV_PI / 4));
    line(img, p, q, colour, 1, LINE_AA);
    p.x = (int)(q.x + 9 * cos(angle - CV_PI / 4));
    p.y = (int)(q.y + 9 * sin(angle - CV_PI / 4));
    line(img, p, q, colour, 1, LINE_AA);
}
double getOrientation(const vector<Point> &pts, Mat &img)
{
    //Construct a buffer used by the pca analysis
    int sz = static_cast<int>(pts.size());
    Mat data_pts = Mat(sz, 2, CV_64F);
    for (int i = 0; i < data_pts.rows; i++)
    {
        data_pts.at<double>(i, 0) = pts[i].x;
        data_pts.at<double>(i, 1) = pts[i].y;
    }
    //Perform PCA analysis
    PCA pca_analysis(data_pts, Mat(), PCA::DATA_AS_ROW);
    //Store the center of the object
    Point cntr = Point(static_cast<int>(pca_analysis.mean.at<double>(0, 0)),
        static_cast<int>(pca_analysis.mean.at<double>(0, 1)));

    //Store the eigenvalues and eigenvectors
    vector<Point2d> eigen_vecs(2);
    vector<double> eigen_val(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        eigen_vecs[i] = Point2d(pca_analysis.eigenvectors.at<double>(i, 0),
            pca_analysis.eigenvectors.at<double>(i, 1));
        eigen_val[i] = pca_analysis.eigenvalues.at<double>(i);
    }
    // Draw the principal components
    circle(img, cntr, 3, Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2);
    Point p1 = cntr + 0.01 * Point(static_cast<int>(eigen_vecs[0].x * eigen_val[0]), static_cast<int>(eigen_vecs[0].y * eigen_val[0]));
    Point p2 = cntr - 0.005 * Point(static_cast<int>(eigen_vecs[1].x * eigen_val[1]), static_cast<int>(eigen_vecs[1].y * eigen_val[1]));
    drawAxis(img, cntr, p1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
    putText(img, s = "Y-axis",  p1, cv::FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 100));
    drawAxis(img, cntr, p2, Scalar(255, 255, 0), 5);
    putText(img, s = "X-axis", p2/1.1 , cv::FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255));
    double angle = atan2(eigen_vecs[0].y, eigen_vecs[0].x); // orientation in radians
    return angle;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Load image
    CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, "{@input | circle3.bmp | input image}");
    parser.about("This program demonstrates how to use OpenCV PCA to extract the orientation of an object.\n");
    parser.printMessage();
    Mat src = imread(parser.get<String>("@input"));
    // Check if image is loaded successfully
    if (src.empty())
    {
        cout << "Problem loading image!!!" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    imshow("src", src);
    // Convert image to grayscale
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(src, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    // Convert image to binary
    Mat bw;
    threshold(gray, bw, 70, 255, THRESH_BINARY | THRESH_OTSU);
    // Find all the contours in the thresholded image
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    findContours(bw, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        // Calculate the area of each contour
        double area = contourArea(contours[i]);
        // Ignore contours that are too small or too large
        if (area < 1e2 || 1e5 < area) continue;
        // Draw each contour only for visualisation purposes
        drawContours(src, contours, static_cast<int>(i), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
        // Find the orientation of each shape
        getOrientation(contours[i], src);

    }

    /// Get the moments
    vector<Moments> mu(contours.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        mu[i] = moments(contours[i]);
    }
    ///  Get the mass centers
    vector<Point2f> mc(contours.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        //add 1e-5 to avoid division by zero
        mc[i] = Point2f(static_cast<float>(mu[i].m10 / (mu[i].m00 + 1e-5)),
            static_cast<float>(mu[i].m01 / (mu[i].m00 + 1e-5)));
        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
            std::stringstream ss; ss << i;
            putText(src, ss.str(), mc[i] + Point2f(10,-10), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255));
        }
    }



    imshow("output", src);



    cout << "\t Info: Area and angle \n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {

        cout << " * Contour[" << i << "]  - Center: "<< mc[i] 
            << " - Area: " << contourArea(contours[i]) << " - Angle X: " << getOrientation(contours[i],src)*180/CV_PI << endl;

    }

    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

The only thing I want to know how to draw the coordinate system in the corner of the image. Because I don't understand the angle results.

The results of the final code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9sQb.jpg

And relevant information: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4vRf.jpg